# libpng12-0 not installing

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dpkg, libraries

TL;DR - my system doesn't want to install libpng12, but many applications depend on that lib. OS - Kali rolling
Hey guys. For the last few days I was trying to troubleshoot this problem I got, when installing python3-opencv using apt. The error I got:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try to run as suggested `apt --fix-broken install`:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpng12-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpng12-0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2294 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/173 kB of archives.
After this operation, 273 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 602063 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.50-2+deb8u3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb (-
-unpack):
 unable to install new version of '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or d
irectory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Since that didn't work, I tried installing from a deb package, using `dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb`:

```
(Reading database ... 602063 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-8) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

And that's where I gave up and decided to ask you all :D
What else could I do to get this library?

Answer (score 1):

`libpng` (providing `libpng12-0`) has been removed from Kali Linux since 2016-04-24.

The `python3-opencv` can be installed through `apt`:

```
sudo apt install opencv
```

`opencv` package provide `python3-opencv`.

You should have the following line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The installation of opencv like you suggested doesnt work, saying, that package isnt found. Also, the problem is, that im not able to install anything else using apt, since it says, i need to have libpng12 first... Any idea what to de then?

Comment: @TomasBabelis I have update my answer.